# Probem with Deja-dup during restore

Tags: 16.04, wine, restore, deja-dup

I just installed Ubuntu few days ago, but here is a problem that I don't know how to solve. When I backup my file by using Deja-dup (that is pre-installed in Ubuntu) everything works just fine. But when I restore the backup it shows `Could not restore the following files. Please make sure you are able to write to them` and usually is `/home/ubuntu/.sudo_as_admin_successful`  pop up. I tried to reinstall ubuntu, but it only works sometimes, most of the time (such as I installed some program or upgrade), it will show up again. Moreover, I tried to install Ubuntu in VirtualBox, and I'm having the same problem there.

I googled that problem, such as YouTube or the previous posts, such as using `sudo deja-dup --restore` or `sudo deja-dup`..., but it didn't work to me. I also tried to use `chmod 666 ./wine`, but it didn't work either. Can anyone give me a helping hand?

*Specs*
 Laptop model: Asus UX305FA
 Ubuntu version: 16.04.2 LTS

askubuntu.com doesn't allow me to to post the details, so I took a screenshot. Also, just in case the image doesn't work, I posted part of it as text:

```
/home/ubuntu/.config/menus/gnome-applications-merged
/home/ubuntu/.mozilla/firefox/2oqnjc5i.default/lock
/home/ubuntu/.sudo_as_admin_successful
/home/ubuntu/.wine/dosdevices/c:
/home/ubuntu/.wine/dosdevices/com1
/home/ubuntu/.wine/dosdevices/com10
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I created a shortcut folder on desktop called "MyLog", and today I tried to backup Linux again by using Deja-dup. The backup was successful, but once I recovered it using the backup few seconds ago, the problem showed up again. But I realize that the "MyLog" folder on the desktop was having the same problem, but the actual MyLog didn't have the same issue. So the result shows that the deja-dup just cannot determine what the type of your file/folder is.